# php dynamic select list

Tags: php, select, logging

I'm trying to work out the best way to create a select dropdown list, based on certain files.

In /logs I have router logs. These can be named `router_log.0` upto `router_log.7`

What I'm trying to do is create a select list, showing just the logs that actually exist. eg if there is on router_log.0 and router_log.1 then only show them.

I know I can hard code this and do if `file_exists` and then echo the line, but is there a better way ?

The select text needs to include the log name and it's date stamp. eg:

```
<option value='0'>router_log.0 (19/10/2016)</option>
<option value='1'>router_log.1 (18/10/2016)</option>
<option value='3'>router_log.3 (16/10/2016)</option>
```

Any idea how I can do this ?

Comment: You do a `glob()` for the log files and then print the found results in a `foreach loop`

Comment: No any way exist unless you get content of file and parse it to get every log.

Comment: Doing `ls -lash router_log*` from the command line returns the correct data, which additional values. is there any way to use that ?

Comment: And for the timestamp, use `filemtime()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [glob()](http://php.net/glob) function for this:

```
foreach (glob("router_log.*") as $filename) {
    $i = str_replace("router_log.","",$filename);
    echo "<option value='$i'>$filename ({filemtime($filename)})</option> ";
}
```